# How to map input to my datalist option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is the following:

HTML:

```
<input list="itemList" id="inputItemList"  type="text" class="form-control">
<datalist id="itemList" >
    <option value="Example" data-id="1">
</datalist>
```

Javascript:

```
var element = $("#inputItemList");
var itemName = element.val();
var id = element.attr('data-id');
```

Through Javascript, I add `<option>`s to my datalist, where every option has custom data in the sort of `data-id`. I may be doing it wrong, but when I query for the value in my `<input>`, I just have the value of the option; I am not able to get the other attributes from my `<option>`. Is there a way around this?

I also tried to get the selected option in `<datalist>` but when I did it, there is nothing selected in it.

Comment: I don't know if you have to support safari but datalist is not supported on that browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the solution. You just have to listen to the input and then check against all the options:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<input list="itemList" id="inputItemList" type="text" class="form-control">

<datalist id="itemList" >
    <option value="Example 1" data-id="1">
    <option value="Example 2" data-id="2">
    <option value="Example 3" data-id="3">
    <option value="Example 4" data-id="4">
</datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change',$('#inputItemList'),function(e){
        var theID = checkOption($(e.target).val());
        if(theID) {
            return console.log('Found match: ' + theID);
        } else {
            return console.log('No Match Found!');
        }
    })
    function checkOption(val) {
        var theID;
        $('#itemList option').each(function(){
            if(val.toLowerCase() == $(this).val().toLowerCase()){
                theID = $(this).data('id');
            }
        })
        return theID;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Basically, when the user has entered something in the input, I want to know what option it corresponds to, because I have custom data linked to that option (ie: I want to know that if he wrote Example in the input, then it is the first option in datalist, so that I can retrieve the data-id value)